# mapView setCenter from subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, dictionary, subview

I'm new to ios programming.

Is it possible to control mapview from subview?

I have viewController called mapview. And mapview has a button to add subview. And that subview was imported in mapview.
In subview I has a table and when i select row on table, I need mapview setCenter to location.

So, how can i do that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Generally, using delegate+protocol is a solution for this kind of communication.  See [Using Delegation to Communicate with Other Controllers in the View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW9).  Note it doesn't apply just to view controllers.

Comment: Wow, that's works. Sorry for asking you such a newbie question.